# total of ratings when using letsrate gem

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm using letsrate gem (https://github.com/muratguzel/letsrate) which allows users to rate different attributes (called 'dimensions') of a model (for eg "Car" model can be rated on "price" & "speed"). the user is also allowed to re-rate the dimensions.

i would like to display the total sum value of the ratings ie latest value of "price" plus latest value of "speed". i would also like to do this so that the total gets refreshed automatically every time the user re-rates any of the dimensions.

after trial & error i tried the following as a helper method:

```
@rate_dimension_1 =Rate.find_by_rater_id_and_rateable_id_and_dimension(@user.id, @object.id, "speed").stars
@rate_dimension_2 = Rate.find_by_rater_id_and_rateable_id_and_dimension(@user.id, @object.id, "price").stars
total_rating = @rate_dimension_1 + @rate_dimension_2
```

but i feel this is very inefficient as i may want to increase the number of dimensions & am sure this will be a slow way to calculate when there are many records. also i would like to store the total in the db which gets updated when any of the ratings are changed.

what would be the best way to do this?

i was thinking i could add a column to the Rate db which stores the sum of all the dimensions. would appreciate help with code for summing up all the latest values of dimensions per user per model id, storing it & then immediately displaying it via ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I think a better way to going about calculating the total rating manually would be with a single query, rather than two queries:

```
total_rating = Rate.sum(:stars, 
  conditions: {rater_id: @user.id, rateable_id: @object.id, dimension: %w(speed price)})
```

If you want to do it over *all* dimensions, you can simply remove the `dimension` condition:

```
total_rating = Rate.sum(:stars, 
  conditions: {rater_id: @user.id, rateable_id: @object.id})
```

This will leave you with a single query to the db regardless of the number of dimensions.

Comment: thanks. this is simpler. now to find a way to save the total to db. will need to go the habtm way i guess & save to a separate db